# Hide, sort or group issues

Tags: sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

How can I hide SonarLint issues? Is it possible to group and sort issues somehow?

I'm using 1.5.0 version of plugin

Thanks

Comment: I'm looking for the same feature as you and I'm using SonarLint 3.0.0.2041 but this is apparently still not possible.